# Bootstrap form. Is there a way to make my file submit button the same as my Submit button?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Good Afternoon Everyone,

I'm looking to create a submit button and upload files button that look the same in bootstrap.  When I use the code below he file upload button just takes me to the top of my page.  Any suggestions?

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group"> 
    <form>
    <button class="btn pull-left" type="inputf" input type="file" name="" value="" placeholder=""> Choose From Files </button> 
    </form> 
    <button class="btn pull-right" type="submit">Send</button> 
</div>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
         <form>
          <button class="btn pull-left" type="inputf" input type="file" name="" value="" placeholder="">
      Choose From Files
      </button>
   </form>
          <button class="btn pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group"> 
    <form>
     Choose From Files <input type="file" name="" value="" placeholder=""><br>
  <button class="btn pull-right" type="submit">Send</button> 
    </form> 
</div>
```

I'm sure you have backend collecting info from this form. Also, I believe you have form action url and method required to make this functional.